# How convert a JSON of a arrayOf JSONArray to an Object

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I have the following JSON array:

```
[
  [
    {
      "body": "Text",
      "bodyType": "Text",
      "nameType": "Text",
      "makeDisplay": "Acura"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "body": "text",
      "bodyType": "text",
      "nameType": "text",
      "makeDisplay": "text"
    }
  ]
]
```

I want to convert it to an object, but the problem is that I have nested arrays and the solution below doesn't work;

```
private var items: List<CarModel> = emptyList()

items = Json(JsonConfiguration.Stable).parse(CarsResponse.serializer().list, "MiJSON.json ....")

@Serializable
data class CarsResponse(
    val items: List<ItemsModels> = emptyList()
)

@Serializable
data class ItemsModels(
    val items: List<CarModel> = emptyList()
)

@Serializable
data class CarModel(
    val body: String = EMPTY_STRING,
    val bodyType: String = EMPTY_STRING,
    val nameType: String = EMPTY_STRING,
    val makeDisplay: String = EMPTY_STRING
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your json from

```
[
 [
{
  "body": "Text",
  "bodyType": "Text",
  "nameType": "Text",
  "makeDisplay": "Acura"
}
],
[
{
  "body": "text",
  "bodyType": "text",
  "nameType": "text",
  "makeDisplay": "text"
 }
 ]
 ]
```

to

```
        [
      {
            "body": "Text",
            "bodyType": "Text",
            "nameType": "Text",
            "makeDisplay": "Acura"
        },
        {
            "body": "text",
            "bodyType": "text",
            "nameType": "text",
            "makeDisplay": "text"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I cant because this is a web service with 8000 values in each row.

Comment: You can use a nested for loop to extract the data from the json and map it into your data class.

Comment: Yes I do that, but i was looking for a native solution . but i couldn't find it